# Instantiate java class from name and memory issues on android

Tags: java, android, class, object, memory

im using this function to instantiate a java class from its name, using its constructor parameters, name, package and constructor parameter types:

```
public Object getObjectFromName(Object[] parameters, String objectName, String packageName, Class[] types) {
    try {
        Class myClass = Class.forName(packageName + objectName);

        if (types == null) {
            types = new Class[parameters.length];

            for (int x = 0; x < parameters.length; x++) {
                types[x] = parameters[x].getClass();
            }
        }
        Constructor constructor = myClass.getConstructor(types);
        Object object = constructor.newInstance(parameters);
        return object;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

Im planning to use this on android devices running 4.4 to create generic fragments (instantiate its objects following a convention). 
It works, but im currently using it only on one object, how about memory leaks on using this approach for 5 or 8 objects? Would it be way slower then common instantiate?

I mean, is this:

```
adapter = (Adapter) getObjectFromName(parameters);
object = (Object) getObjectFromName(parameters);
dao= (Dao) getObjectFromName(parameters);
object2 = (Object2) getObjectFromName(parameters);
object3 = (Object3) getObjectFromName(parameters);
```

Way too slower (and user perceptive) than:

```
adapter = (Adapter) new Adapter(parameters);
object = (Object) new Object(parameters);
dao= (Dao) new Dao(parameters);
object2 = (Object2) new Object2(parameters);
object3 = (Object3) new Object3(parameters);
```

Comment: It is not clear from your question how a "memory leak" could occur from this code. Can you please refine your question as to what exactly you want to achieve ?

Comment: I tried to add more info. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I understand what you are trying to do. You want to have a *common constructor* of sorts that instantiates objects through reflection. While this is no doubt intelligent, let us consider whether it is also *intuitive*:

Is

```
adapter = (Adapter) getObjectFromName(parameters);
```

more *clear* and *intuitive* than

```
adapter = (Adapter) new Adapter(parameters);
```

When we create new abstractions, we need to consider whether they are

- efficient.
- reusable & widely applicable.
- easy & intuitive, i.e. they considerably reduce the programmer's work.

I personally don't believe that creating a common constructor like this is particularly interesting as an abstraction. When I create a new object by calling one of its constructors

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(this);
```

its obvious to anyone else reading my code that I'm creating a new object of a class `Adapter` with the current `Activity` as context.

And moreover, as you rightly said, using reflection to create new class instances is less efficient than directly calling its constructor(s).

So you need to determine whether this new abstraction that you intend to create is particularly beneficial to you and others who would read your code.

Comment: Thank your for your time ZygoteInit. The meaning of this abstraction aint code readability, but lets say i could create an entire fragment using just conventions, i could even instantiate a new fragment given a object type (name) without creating a class file. Instead of having 10 fragment files with 10 instantiates in each , i could have 10 lines, that create these 10 fragments on the fly. 
  It looks promising, but i dont know if this approach can be used on a cell phone, maybe this kind of implementation is to heavy, and should only be done on desktops, what do you think?

Comment: I understood that one of the reasons for this was avoiding code duplication. But the truth is, you won't always be adding & removing `Fragment`s, you will also be performing other operations. The `FragmentManager` and `FragmentTransaction` classes have many other methods. If I were you, I would prefer to explicitly know what operations I am performing with a `Fragment`. But its really upto you, what you think think of this approach, and if you feel it solves more problems for you then of course you should go ahead with it ... best :)

Comment: @sagits: where have you reached with this ?

Comment: Ive been using reflection on my projects. I have searched a lot and found that theres no overall performance issue. Althrought reflection is slower than generics and normal instantiation, its still not noticeable for human eyes.

Comment: @sagits: if you feel that this answer was useful, please mark it as correct. Thanks :) .... and of course, you're right about it not being visible to the human eye.